# Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI) in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard (version 10.50.1600.1) and tried to restore database with bakup
of same version of sql server 2008 R2. but it tells the error Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Comment: You need to specify the exaclty error or much better and screencast, but first of all, check on google... .

Comment: why don't try to use the Sql management to restore the .bak, I avoid use script for restore, or you dont have alternative?.

Comment: may b bak file is corrupted, bcoz i can restore old bak file. Let me take another bakup and check. but how can it corrupted after 1 person restored successfully?

Comment: yea, Bakup was corrupted, sometimes silly mistakes are make lot of time waste.....

Comment: maybe you take wrong .bak file?.

Comment: NO. Actually one of my friend restored same .bak file. After then i tried to restore then it failed.